# UITextField added to contentView of UITableViewCell does not display properly in Popover (iPad, iOS 4.2)

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uitextfield, popover

I'm trying to display a table of choices in a popover on the iPad. I'm adding a UITextField to the default UITableViewCell. The table is configured as a sectioned table.

It does not draw correctly and is not displayed.
If the row is selected, the UITextField becomes visible. If you click another row, it disappears.

I've played with subview order to no avail. What has worked has been to set UITableViewCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].

If I do that, I think need to set the color somewhere else such as the content view, UITableViewCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

However, it still does not display correctly. It looks fine when its not selected, or selected. But if I programmatically set an accessory checkmark, half of the background of the accessory checkmark shows up clear with the darker color of the table background.

If the row is selected, it looks ok, but if another row is selected, as the row with the UITextField is being de-selected, for a fraction of a second, you see half of the accessory background clear (transparent).

Any ideas or suggestions of what might be wrong or how to work around this? The Apple docs clearly state that adding a view to the ContentView is an appropriate way to implement it, yet it does not appear to work in this case.

Here's the code I currently have within tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 10, 60, 26)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.text = @"foo";
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
[textField release];

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Maybe show a screenshot or more of your popover code.

Comment: What additional code could be useful to see?

Answer (score 0):

In general the place to set a UITableViewCell's backgroundColor is not tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. You must do it in +tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:+.

You should not need to change the contentView's backgroundColor.

Comment: Doesn't explain why it doesn't work. It doesn't display unless the contentView's backgroundColor is changed.